# Homestead 9 fresh box creating a new Laravel project composer Could not scan for classes inside /vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am trying to set up Homestead as a development environment and am not having much luck. I follow the instructions to get Homestead up and running on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#installation-and-setup. The box comes up fine and I can shell in with vagrant ssh. In the code directory which is mapped correctly to a directory on my Windows machine I create a new laravel project with `laravel new example` and I get the following error

```
[RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "/home/vagrant/code/example/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

I have tried `composer update` `rm -rf vendor && composer install` and get the same error. When I use `composer install --prefer-source` I don't have the install error, but get

```
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

and
    `In LoadConfiguration.php line 68:
Unable to load the "app" configuration file.`

I have checked that I have a .env file and I have checked that the app file name and path is in lowercase.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update VirtualBox to v6.

See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1219

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the issue